# Breaking Fast everyday

Tags: sawm

Salam! I am breaking my fast everyday (before iftar time to occur) via making intention to break it but not with need of water or food. It's shaytan waswasas that I act upon. I start having ocd related to my fast that when my fast starts I keep saying, "I am not breaking my fast" but when shaytan waswasas occur I make intention to break it. This never happened in previous months of ramdhan. And at end I have become less motivated to fast in this month of ramdhan (my intention to fast is lost). I hope Allah will forgive me and give me solution for it.

Do I need to make up the days for fast consecutively?